# Sending information to a php file from AJAX and getting a response back from php not when I want to

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a contact page that I'm working on and I coded it so that if an invalid email is sent through, php sends back a response, but the way it is coded now, it sends back that message is a field is missing or nothing is filled in at all and someone clicks send. You can view it at http://sundayfundayleague.com/contact.php

I still want the normal HTML5 'required' fields to take place and then if the email field is not right for the php else response.. `"Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";` to then show up.

How can I do this?

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
}
```

AJax call

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#submit').click(function(){

                    $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
                        if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                             }, 2000);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactFail");
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                             }, 2000);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform" >
                <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <!--
                <input type="message" class="inputbarmessage" name="message" placeholder="Message" required>
                -->
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                <label for="contactButton">
                    <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Send Message" id="submit">
                </label>
            </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding exit; after your invalid email response?

Comment: Wouldn't that make the messages not display though?

Comment: Not if you put the exit; AFTER the message: echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";exit;

Comment: Still get it with exit;

Comment: If I hit submit without any info filled in the contact form, I still get the invalid email div show up. I don't want that to show up unless it is actually an invalid email. I want the required messages to show up.

Comment: So you need to check if the $email field is filled in first, then check if it is valid.  Do a nested case here.

Comment: A nested case? What is that

Comment: See the answer I've posted, it's just looking at the email variable to see if it's not empty.  Then and only then will your 'email check' code run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check if the email address has been filled out first.  Something like this should do it.

```
if (!empty($email)) { 
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

        //Should also do a check on the mail function
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
        } else {
            echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
        }

    } else { 
        //Invalid email
        echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
    }

} else {
    //$email was not filled out
}
```

Comment: I get this error for the new else line.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in

Comment: Sorry, forgot to close an if statement in there.

Comment: Thanks! This is a little off topic, but after I try to send it and I get an error, I have to reload the page again to try to send anything. Is there a way to allow me to try to send it again with a reload?

Comment: Yeah, instead of using $.post, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  Another tip, when you're debugging javascript, the browser console is essential.  You can utilize `console.log("test");` in your javascript to return anything you need to for debugging purposes.

Comment: No problem, if you're still running into issues, PM me and I'll take a closer look.  Good luck!